# vertically aligning a form and its opposite content in bootstrap using display:table , display:table-cell , display:table-row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

i have a problem aligning a form in bootstrap basically my problem is not as scary as the question might suggest , let me elaborate:

i have very simple markup , something that goes like this :

```
<section class="contactus" id="contactus">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <address>
                              No. 311,<br> 
                            11th Main, <br>
                            120 Feet Road, <br>
                            indonasia<br>
                              calcutta,<br>
                            pondichury<br>
                        </address>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <form action="" role="form">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">SEND</button>    
                            </div>  
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div> <!-- end of container -->
        </section>
```

and very simple css too :

```
.contactus{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.contactus .container{
    display: table !important;
    height: 100%;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.contactus .row{
    display: table-row !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

.contactus .col-md-6{
    display: table-cell !important;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

now what the above css is actually suppose to do is vertically align the two col-md-6's in the center of .contactus class , which of course take 100% height on any given screen .

and than inside each col-md-6 the content should be horizontally in the middle of the col-md-6 .

neither of which happen .

now i did a few test , and here are the surprising results :

first let me post a link to the entire code :

[code link : (load the link in your browser and wait for 10 secound for the code to appear)](http://chopapp.com/#xz6r4d4j)

i am going to keep the same css with and without bootstrap , So with bootstrap :

[image: withbootstrap]

and without bootstrap(just remove the cdn )

[image: without bootstrap]

now without bootstrap , i am vertually getting what i want . WHY ?? Because the

```
display:table;
display:table-cell;
display:table-row;
```

all three function in tandem , to give me the result that i coded for .

so what happens with bootstrap :

**Answer :** well i discovered today morning that the float property in css breaks the display chain(**as floating an element makes its display set to block**) and indeed in my code i have 2 col-md-6's which are nothing but floated elements under the hood .

so as it stands , i am almost there , but not there yet.

One more important thing :

now if i took off the col-md-6's completely and insteaded added the following code in the css :

```
address, form{
    display: table-cell !important;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

i again get the result i want but , without the col-md-6's my layout is rendered Not-responsive , so well how do i get around this problem ??

**all i want at the end of the day is a responsive design and vertical alignment .**

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Alexander.

Comment: Side Note: Hard to debug something that burns your eyes... Use a softer colour, that red is painful.

Comment: taught red stands for attractive , nevertheless will change that to #eee maybe :D